# Wordpress - Custom linking to an external file outside of media library

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I build a website using  the wordpress and my goal is to make a link to a shared .xls file on local Lan (no internet on this Lan) without upload this file into the media library and all coworkers on the network can have the ability to open and edit this file.

Is it posible?

Comment: If it windows or linux? If it's windows and you have any file shared like txt or html, you can drag it into browser in browser you have link like file:\\directory you need this link but don't open it on your PC (unless you'll open your own shared folder in LAN and not directly at your drive) but on someone else - link will be the same for everybody.

Comment: It's windows. I will try it out. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: How am I going to add that link into my website? Custom links doesnt accept  links with file://///192.168.1.12/ format on wordpress.

Comment: I managed to make loaded but the file is read only and every time you have to save it with a new name so its not suitable.

Comment: Maybe do the same but map folder to some domain in hosts file - it's just idea I haven't tried.